Is PowerShell Test-Connection command from another PC cause loosing data between the wi-fi device and server
We have a Wi-Fi device and a Server which is communicates always. And I need to check are they communicating. What I am doing? I am running the PowerShell / Test-Connection command to check the Wi-Fi device port 3700 is reachable or not. Wi-Fi device sometimes loosing connection to server. That's why I need to check it.
The command is:
PowerShell / Test-NetConnection 192.168.6.105 -port 3700
Is that command from CLIENT cause mis-communication of the DEVICE and SERVER?
CLIENT -> (Device & Server)
If cause, is there any safe command or do I have to update my command with a parameter?
My goal is not to connect to the device, but just to find out whether PORT 3700 is open or not. Why I need to update my command or another alternative command because the other guys says don't do that because I will disturb their communication if I run that command.

The Wi-Fi device which I want to check is: 192.168.6.105 -port 3700

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It depends on how that port is used in your environment. For example, UDP may very well lose packets, SSL checks data integrity. Why don't you test it? Check throughput and integrity while running that test in a loop.

1/2 I began editing your post to make it more clear, but then I realized I do not understand what you are asking. The only problem you specifically note is "Wi-Fi device sometimes loosing connection to server." But then you ask "Is that command from CLIENT cause mis-communication of the DEVICE and SERVER?" I don't know, is it? It shouldn't, but what context you have given seems to indicate it might be? Please CLARIFY all of the problems you are experiencing.

2/2  You have done well enough expressing yourself so far, even English perhaps not being an easy language for you, so don't worry about trying to make the English more clear: I am pretty sure that we can edit your post to clarify the language once you've got all of the information in it. But please EDIT your post to add all of the information necessary for us to understand all of the problems you are experiencing that you need help solving.


Is that command from CLIENT cause mis-communication of the DEVICE and SERVER?

The command opens a new TCP connection; it does nothing to test an existing connection.
So in theory it's possible for it to interrupt an existing connection, but highly unlikely, unless the 'server' software is incredibly badly programmed. The risk is low (usually zero, I'd hope) for services running on a full OS (like on Linux) where the OS provides reliable TCP/IP handling, and somewhat higher for tiny embedded devices which might have a poorly tested TCP implementation in their firmware.

My goal is not to connect to the device, but just to find out whether PORT 3700 is open or not.

Test-NetConnection can't do that; the only way it tests 'port open' is by connecting to it.
And really that is the only way to test this, although tools like nmap have tricks (such as aborting the TCP handshake halfway). But if an ordinary connection somehow disrupts the service, it's likely that an nmap scan will confuse it even more.
Note that it is probably impossible to non-disruptively check whether an existing TCP connection is still alive – and that's not the same as checking whether the TCP listening port is 'open'. (For example, if it's a device that only supports one connection at a time, then it might even give you the opposite result: rejecting the test connection when a real connection is alive, and the other way around...)

Hi, Thank you very much for your valuable answer. In the illumination of what you said is there any difference between (PS / Test-NetConnection) and (CMD / TELNET 192.168.6.105 3700)?

As far as I know there should be practically no difference. They both create a TCP connection. (There could be slight differences, e.g. the TELNET command might actually send Telnet protocol handshake over the connection which the server might misunderstand... but I think it only does so on the default port, and sends nothing on custom ports.)

I forgot to mention. The PowerShell command is also included the port. Test-Netconnection 192.168.6.105 -port 3700. I think both are equal. Thank you very much for your time. Happy new year.
